# HttpListener instantly closes connection when using https?

Tags: c#

I have a service built on `HttpListener`. Works fine on standard http. It closes connections instantly when listening on and receiving connections from `wss` (https).

I'm on Linux, 90% of the web is talking about how Windows reads certificates, but where does it get this for Linux? and is the fact it could not be finding a certificate be the reason?

I've added a `X509Certificate2` to the store but still connection drops.

I've also added an event handler for validating certificates like so:
`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (_, _, _, _) => true;`

Comment: When you say Linux you presumably are on .Net Core and in that context ServicePointManager does not really. You should be on HttpClient and you need to register the Callback with that HttpClient. Ok i'm slightly wrong just seeing that you mentioned HttpListener.

Comment: And to be correct here you tried to add a ValidationCallback to **NOT** validate the certificate.

Comment: @Ralf I've tried both.

Comment: My knowledge about HttpListener is slim but afaik its build around http.sys so its a pure Windows thing. If this is a new development look at Asp.Net Core.

Comment: Are you seeing an exception? Please post the full message (along with any InnerException). You need a Wireshark trace to see the Server Hello and Client Hello, to see if there is a mismatched version or cipher list. Also `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` don't do this, it's a bad idea, and anyway does nothing from the server's side, it only works on the client.

Comment: Seems like its just not supported https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/19752